# Add a security layer to our SQL Servers (currently accesible from remote sql management studio)

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003

We have a big system running with thousands of users (some from android apps, other from the web app, etc.).

The system is distributed, with databases in two locations (within the same country). In one location there are 5 servers in the same network, and each one has a copy of the database (via replication).

Among the software developers, a few have direct access to the production databases. Sometimes due to technical support requested by users to modify some operations not possible from the system itself, the developers/support team have to access the database directly and modify some records.

We know this is not the ideal manner of working. But it's been like this since years.

Recently we have found a few problems. One day one person updated hundreds of records from a table by mistake.

Since then we are analyzing how to improve this access.

We are looking for some way of improving the security. We would like to have a two-phase authentication system in place. Something that asks the user for two passwords when accessing from Sql Server Management Studio...

Is that possible? Or is there any other approach we can use to improve the security but still allow devs/support team to access the production database when necessary?

Users also (currenty) have access via remote desktop to all servers.

At least we would like to KNOW when this access is being done.

Comment: Do you currently use Windows Authentication or Mixed-Mode Authentication? How do you handle permissions for users from the application?

Comment: how do you think asking a password twice will prevent `One day one person updated hundreds of records from a table by mistake.`

Comment: @ArthurD Yes, it has mixed-mode enabled.

Comment: @TheGameiswar the idea would be that the 1st password would be available to 2 people only. So they would be present and watching over the shoulder of the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Make access to PROD read only for those users. Allow them to write their scripts and then submit them for review at a minimum and testing if possible like any other deployable. Then follow standard deployment processes with someone who has access.

Comment: Hi @SMM, I like your solution. We were thinking maybe of a mix between a repository (SVN) and Jenkins. For example, a support guy wants to update some rows, or tables. So, he writes a script (SQL), runs the script on our Dev sever (this server every night takes a very fresh backup of the production system and recreates its own database from it). Once the support guy is happy with the script he commits it to a special SVN repository (called support). Once this happens someone with DB write rights checks the script and launches a job on Jenkins. This job runs the script on production.

Comment: So this changes would be made through Jenkins (no one would have direct access). Only the right to exec the job on jenkins. However, we are afraid this way may be too limiting for the user writing the sQL script. As it's really easier to modify the values having a visual representation of a row on the screen using a specific software like EMS SQL Manager for SQL Server.

Comment: Is using a SVN repository for this a crazy idea? Is there already some other sort of software for this specific job we are missing? Thanks

Comment: In the environment we are in we are not that far along with DB automation. We still build deployment scripts that are run by the DBA but they would be tested first in a pre-PROD environment and then QA and/or UAT would have a crack at the results to make sure nothing is broken. However...this is where we are starting investigations in the very near future...it might be partially helpful - again depending on what you are scripting: [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlJmY29Rqjo) and [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JefcR3KS8pk).

Answer (score 0):

If my other answer isn't workable and these updates are always the same kind of fixes...you could create support stored procs maybe to do the fixes and only give permission on the procs...but this is highly dependent on the commonality of fixes being made and less preferable to my other answer.

I haven't used it myself but [EXECUTE AS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) might let you give the users read-only permission while the procs would execute under credentials with higher access.

Comment: But limit the damage of forgetting a where clause on a delete statement 

Comment: Well true, but I'm not holding out hope for an IT team that runs an app with thousands of users "for years" with no database change control mechanisms ...

Comment: Perhaps this could be a stepping stone to a more ideal solution...a gradual civilization of the wild west 